# laravel convert to string mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have this code written in using the laravel and I wonder how to write it in pure SQL without using laravel, as would be?

```
    Route::get('popular', function(){

    $media = Media::where('active', '=', '1')->join('media_likes', 'media.id', '=', 'media_likes.media_id')->groupBy('media_likes.media_id')->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(media_likes.id)'), 'DESC')->select('media.*')->paginate(30);

    $data = array(
        'media' => $media,
        'categories' => Category::all(),
        'pages' => Page::all(),
        'settings' => Setting::first(),
        );

    return View::make('Theme::home', $data);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using `toSql` method

Laravel Query builder has a helpful method called `toSql` which is handy to see what the final SQL query looks like.

Now, when you call the `paginate` method, you'll get a `Paginator` and you won't be able to call the `toSql` method.

#### Deconstructing `paginate`

When you use `paginate`, Laravel will make the following query for each `$page`:

```
// Let's simplify the query for now
Media::skip(($page - 1) * $perPage)->take($perPage);
```

Knowing that, you can use the query builder's method `toSql` and you'll see the actual sql string.

Supossing `$page=3`, `$perPage=30`, and that the name of the table is **media**, you'll get something like this:

```
Media::skip(2 * 30)->take(30)->toSql();
```

> select * from media limit 30 offset 60

---

**Now, for your actual query, you can use the following to see the resulting SQL string for the page 3** (as an example):

```
Media::where('active', '=', '1')
    ->join('media_likes', 'media.id', '=', 'media_likes.media_id')
    ->groupBy('media_likes.media_id')
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(media_likes.id)'), 'DESC')
    ->select('media.*')
    ->skip(2 * 30)
    ->take(30)
    ->toSql();
```

---

### [Listening For Query Events](https://laravel.com/docs/master/database#listening-for-query-events)

Alternatively, you can set an event listener in your `AppServiceProvider`, and log each SQL query the application executes.

```
public function boot()
{
    \DB::listen(function ($query) {
        \Log::debug($query->sql);
        \Log::debug($query->bindings);
        \Log::debug($query->time);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$media = Media::where('active', '=', '1')->join('media_likes', 'media.id', '=', 'media_likes.media_id')->groupBy('media_likes.media_id')->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(media_likes.id)'), 'DESC')->select('media.*')->paginate(30);
```

Something like this:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM
media m
JOIN 
media_likes ml
ON
ml.media_id = m.id
GROUP BY 
ml.media_id
ORDER BY
COUNT(ml.id) DESC
```